# Delete Object from Core data relationship - NSSet

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a one to many relationship between a Product entity and a Cart Entity.

The user needs to have the opportunity to delete a product from the cart.

I fetch the products like so:

```
         // Fetch request for "Product":
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Product"];

// Fetch only products for the cart:
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"inCart = %@", self.cart];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate]; 


NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"navn" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_theManagedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

and populate the tableview:

```
Product *prod = (Product *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

In the tableview I have a button and when you tap it, that current product, should get deleted... I have the following code in my "delete product method"

```
-(void)RemoveFromCart:(UIButton *)sender {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [_Table indexPathForCell:cell];

    Product *prod = (Product *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    /*_cart is retrieved when the user pushes the add to cart button, in another    viewcontroller, a cart object is then returned and passed to the cart viewcontroller */
    NSMutableSet *mutableSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:_cart.products];

        [mutableSet removeObject:prod];
        _cart.products = mutableSet;



    [self saveCurrentContext:_theManagedObjectContext];


    [_Table reloadData];




}
```

But nothing happens, when the method is fired.. the product is not removed from the relationship. 
How do I manage to fix this, my code is obviously wrong somewhere.

Comment: Do you want to *delete* the product or just remove it from the cart?

Comment: Remove it from the cart :).. thank you Martin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To remove a product from the cart, you can either use

```
product.inCart = nil;
```

or

```
[_cart removeProductsObject:product];
```

(Both lines are equivalent if the inverse relationships are properly set up.)

Comment: what if inverse relationship is not set

Comment: @ArpitBParekh: Then the second version should still work – but you should always define inverse relationships, there is no reason not to do so.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin for quick reply.

Comment: Hi MArtin Can you guide me step by step

Answer (score 0):

```
[_theManagedObjectContext deleteObject:product];
```

This only worked for me after Xcode 7. 
Maybe because of the changes introduced about the entity+CoreDataProperties category creation?